# How can I get the project path in Scala?

Tags: eclipse, file, scala, io, path

I'm trying to read some files from my Scala project, and if I use: `java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath()` I find that my current directory is far away from them (exactly where I have installed Scala Eclipse). So how can I change the current directory to the root of my project, or get the path to my project? I really don't want to have an absolute path to my input files.

```
  val PATH = raw"E:\lang\scala\progfun\src\examples\"
  def printFileContents(filename: String) {
    try {
      println("\n" + PATH + filename)
      io.Source.fromFile(PATH + filename).getLines.foreach(println)
    } catch {
      case _:Throwable => println("filename " + filename + " not found")
    }
  }

  val filenames = List("random.txt", "a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt")
  filenames foreach printFileContents
```

Comment: [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) is the best modern solution for managing paths with Scala and reading files [as described here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/).  The Java filesystem libraries are messy and should be avoided whenever possible now that this great alternative exists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Add your files to `src/main/resources/<packageName>` where `<packageName>` is your class package.
2. Change the line `val PATH = getClass.getResource("").getPath`

Comment: Well, in my case (on Windows 8) the path returned is  <project_path>/bin/<packageName>/ which is just what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
new File(".").getCanonicalPath
```

will give you the base-path you need

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to put the path you need in an user environmental variable, and call it with *sys.env* (returns exception if failure) or *System.getenv* (returns null if failure), for example `val PATH = sys.env("ScalaProjectPath")` but the problem is that if you move the project you have to update the variable, which I didn't want.